# ios10 directory extension send some strange error messages

Tags: ios10

I try to develop an extension to identify incoming call phoneNumber, but there were some errores during my developing , which i never have met before.
The app seems to work when i test API for this extension.
But when i used For cycle (for...in...) to add identification like this

```
CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber phoneNumber = model.COL_NUM2.longLongValue;
[context addIdentificationEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:phoneNumber label:content];
```

it comes to send two error messages at this function.

```
CXCallDirectoryManager *manager = [CXCallDirectoryManager sharedInstance];
[manager reloadExtensionWithIdentifier:extensionIdentifier completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {}];
```

If my cycle count is more than 20 the error code is 2 which means CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerErrorLoadingInterrupted. If cycle count is less than 20 and the parameter, which is called content in this demo, contains a special string, which is just an normal name, the error code is 3 that means CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerErrorEntriesOutOfOrder.

I don't know how to solve this problem after i searched it in google and baidu and got none useful answer.